# Javascript not working (Not showing alert box)

Tags: javascript, php, html

**Main Form**

I m trying to make a feedback form but unable to get the values of radio button.
I m using BootStrap and PHP.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="feedbackForm" role="form" method="post" action="adddetails.php">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <tr>
    <td><b>No.</b></td>
    <td><b>Parameter</b></td>
    <td align="center" colspan="5"><b>Faculty</b></td>
  </tr>
        <td></td>
        <td align="right"><b>Faulty Name</b> <i>[Abbreviation]</i></td>
        <td><b>JS</b></td>
        <td><b>AT</b></td>
        <td><b>GK</b></td>
        <td><b>PS</b></td>
        <td><b>SB</b></td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
        <td></td>
        <td align="right"><b>Subject Code</b></td>
        <td><b>MCA 202</b></td>
        <td><b>MCA 204</b></td>
        <td><b>MCA 206</b></td>
        <td><b>MCA 208</b></td>
        <td><b>MCA 210</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
        <td>1.</td>
        <td>ontact forms are one of the most common elements found on a web page, and they can be used to gather just about any type of information required from your users.</td>
        <td align="center">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="jsq1">1
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="jsq1">2
            </label></br>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="jsq1">3
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="jsq1">4
            </label></br>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="jsq1">5
            </label>
       </td>

       <td align="center">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="atq1">1
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="atq1">2
            </label></br>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="atq1">3
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="atq1">4
            </label></br>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="atq1">5
            </label>
       </td>

       <td align="center">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="gkq1">1
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="gkq1">2
            </label></br>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="gkq1">3
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="gkq1">4
            </label></br>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="gkq1">5
            </label>
       </td>

       <td align="center">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="psq1">1
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="psq1">2
            </label></br>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="psq1">3
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="psq1">4
            </label></br>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="psq1">5
            </label>
       </td>

       <td align="center">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="sbq1">1
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="sbq1">2
            </label></br>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="sbq1">3
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="sbq1">4
            </label></br>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="sbq1">5
            </label>
       </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

AddDetails.php

```
<?php

    $jsq1 = $_POST['jsq1'];
    echo "$jsq1";

    $atq1 = $_POST['atq1'];
    echo "$atq1";
?>
```

I want to get values of radio button and add to mysql but this is showing out put

```
onon
```

How to get values like 1,2,3,4 and 5 that can I add into the database.

Comment: Use the HTML attribute `value`.

Comment: there is no javascript code in this question.

Comment: And there is no mysql

Answer (score 1):

You must have to write `value` attribute

```
<input type="radio" name="sbq1" value="3">
```

so when form is submitted, `3` will be submitted to server

Answer (score 1):

As said, you need to add a `value` attribute:

```
<input type="radio" name="sbq1" value="1">1
```

`value` is the actual value that will be submitted.

---

You can use this to automatically add the `value` attribute:

```
$('input[type=radio]').each(function () {
    $(this).attr('value', $(this).parent().text());
});
```